# Postfix with letsencryt not working

Tags: postfix, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup my own email server. I have installed postfix and dovecot. I created an SSL certificate using letsencrypt.

I have set web interface to use that certificate, but how do I get postfix to use it. This is what I put in the main.cf file:

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/main.declanmarks.pw/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.declanmarks.pw/fullchain.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

When I try to connect gmail android app to the outgoing server I keep getting `454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problems`.

What would the correct configuration to use letsencrypt on postfix.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It wasn't very obvious because I didn't notice. There was a spelling mistake.

Comment: Usually, questions that hinge on spelling mistakes aren't going to be useful to other people. If you think this is one of those questions, you can delete your own question. Otherwise, it'd be nice if you could extend your answer to point at the spelling mistake (I'm assuming it was `main.declanmarks.pw` that was the error). It would also be helpful if you'd add log lines from the server email logs which would likely point out that the server couldn't find that file. That will be more helpful to future seekers of answers.